# why Hibernate 5.2.17 doesn't accept zonedate form?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

I'm beginner in hibernate mysql programming, i developed java classes, and I've a problem in my hibernate.cfg.xml file syntax:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false</property>
```

This property has a wrong syntax and my config can't access my database.
I work on eclipse oxygen IDE and hibernate 5.2.17

Comment: Hi, can you edit your question and post the contents of the hibernate.cfg.xml in there?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem like a week ago, it said the problem was with the zone date, I have the same syntax in my hibernate.cfg.xml, but then I read that that wasn't the problem. The way I solved it, was adding the mysqlConnector.jar in the Classpath.

You add it in, Run Configurations -> Classpath -> Select User Entries -> Add External JARs -> Select mysqlConnector.jar -> Apply

**Note 1**: In the hibernate.cfg.xml you can just write it like this: 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase

**Note 2:** It might show you the same problem in the Hibernate Configuration Tab, but it will run it correctly anyways.